# Property or field 'config' cannot be found on null

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am trying to Implement ***InitializingBean*** on my ***StudentDaoImpl.class*** and in the function ***afterPropertiesSet()*** trying to execute an expression using ***ExpressionParser***, but Spring is saying that property config is not found or is null even if I have declared config in my ***App.propperties***.

***AppConfig.class***(Configuration Class)

```
package config;

import dao.StudentDAOImpl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:App.properties")
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean("jdbcTemplete")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate();
        template.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return template;
    }
    @Bean("dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springjdbc");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("root");
        return ds;
    }
    @Bean("StudentDaoImpl")
    public StudentDAOImpl studentDaoImpl() {
        StudentDAOImpl studentdao = new StudentDAOImpl(jdbcTemplate());
        return studentdao;
    }
    @Bean("getProperties")
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getProperties() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

***StudentDaoImpl.class*** (I have removed methods of StudentDao Interface from the code below for you to see properly)

```
package dao;

import entities.Student;
import mapper.StudentMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.expression.Expression;
import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import java.util.List;

public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO, InitializingBean {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Value("${config}")
    String s;

    public StudentDAOImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        System.out.println(s);
        Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression("config");
        String result = (String)expression.getValue();
        System.out.println(result);
//        if(result == true) {
//            System.out.println("[Configuration]: Java Configuration");
//        } else {
//            System.out.println("[Configuration]: XML Configuration");
//        }
    }
}
```

***App.properties***

```
config=java
```

Also, I have seen that I was able to access the property from App.properties using @Value but not with ExpressionParser, Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

?

You are parsing a String, not the field; use

```
Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression(config);
```

to parse an expression in field `config` - however the value `java` is not a valid expression.

It is not at all clear what you are trying to do.